# Printing conjunct unicode characters using single keystroke

Tags: xorg, keyboard, unicode

I want to print a conjunct unicode characters (which do not have dedicated unicode value assigned to it, but which can be print using the combination of unicode characters) using a single key stroke by modifying the keyboard layout in Linux. I am modifying the /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbol/in file to modify the layout. Let me know if anything is possible.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of what do you want to do, but, if it may help I use xim and a custom `$HOME/.XCompose` (on a per user configuration basis) to remap custom key (two chars sequence mapped to a unique key, composition rules for dead key).